# Exercises with solutions in dimensional analysis - reference request

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education, dimensional-analysis

I am currently trying to brush up on my skills in dimensional analysis, and computing with units. Is there a good source of worked examples, and exercises with solutions? I'd prefer to have solutions by my side in order to see whether I can improve my approach and way of thinking.

Comment: Most introductory physics textbooks have dimensional analysis in the first chapter, like Resnick and Halliday.

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon for [dimensional analysis physics](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=dimensional+analysis+physics&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Adimensional+analysis+physics) books?

Comment: @Cicero I was hoping for a reference that focusses on this topic

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks! Yes I looked at Amazon before but on the UK site (which wasn't as helpful)

Comment: Could you then provide a short list of the books that you *didn't* like (and what you didn't like about it) from your Amazon search? It might help the answerers from promoting a book that you did not find satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this [Oxford Summer School note](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/tutorials/DALectureNotes11.pdf) solely about dimensional analysis, and requires no prerequisites. It covers dimensional analysis up to Buckingham Pi theorem, with an elementary
treatment of a fun example of the role of viscosity: how do bubbles rise in a fluid?

For a more advanced treatment, you can try this [Ain A. Sonin note](http://web.mit.edu/2.25/www/pdf/DA_unified.pdf). This note provides some of the applications and solves more complex problems related to dimensional analysis.